# How can I not use Castle Windsor for a specific ASP.NET Controller

Tags: asp.net, autocomplete, castle

I have an application that uses Castle Windsor to create the Controllers and all descendant objects.  The Castle Root has about 1200 total objects in it and can take a bit of time to create the controller and descendant objects, typically this is not an issue as it is only about 25-30% of time based on running visual studio Performance Monitoring.

In the application I have a type ahead (autocomplete) control where the user starts typing and a possible list of choices is returned.  This method takes between 1-1.5 seconds.  Which is a bit annoying for a type ahead.  I want it under 1/2 sec.  the time spent in the actually controller method is around .1-.2 seconds.

So what I'm looking for is a way to speed this method up.  If I could create a controller that was not part of Castle Windsor that would remove 30% of time bringing the time it takes down to .6-.9 seconds, which would be much better.

So is there a way to have a Controller that is not created through Castle, but normal ASP.NET Controller creation, or is there a different better way to speed this method up.

Comment: I am really surprised by the amount of time you are reporting for the controller resolution. Are you sure this is only Castle? Aren't some other initialisation that may be responsible for the time?

Comment: I ended up creating another controller that didn't have any references and that one took the majority of the time.  So the time was not in creating the controller, but in creating all of the other things that the controller was referencing.